# Mobile display - projection on monitor

Tags: mobile, testing

I would like to get the most simple solution for user testing on mobiles and tablets. For desktop we use Morae. Easy to record, easy to edit, easy to share. But what about mobiles and tablets?

There are three ways I can think of:

1. Find a specific software used to record use on mobile devices.
   I'm afraid there is no freeware and the company I'm working for will be not willing to buy other software.
2. Skip record-on-device and try to record mobile on a typical camera.
   Very difficult to handle properly, usually the testers can't move the device so they can't work as they usually would...
3. Maybe it's useless - but is there someone who tried something like projection of mobile display to the typical NTB monitor and there record with Morae?

Comment: Unfortunately ANY sw for the desktop is out of question - security politics. I can install only on the mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Apple phone:

- Connect the phone to a Mac computer using a cable
- Open Quicktime and click `File > New Movie Recording` in the menu
- Click the little arrow next to the red recording button and select your phone from the menu
- Press red recording button to start recording

The only downside is that you need to have a cable connected to the phone during the test. None of our participants complained about this though.

Answer (score 1):

I typically work with 2. It's great because it's the only option you listed that also captures the user's hands and fingers.  Jake Knapp (Google X) follows this practice and gives some tips in his book "Sprint" and Mailchimp uses this practice as well.  Here's [a post from Mailchimp](https://blog.mailchimp.com/in-the-lab-mobile-usability-testing/) with images of their setup.

In Mailchimp's case as well as in Indeed's, they have special rooms set up for mobile testing.  A more DIY approach is totally doable.  In grad school I just set a camera up on a tripod behind someone and it captured the scene pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up **Teamviewer**. Connect the device with your monitoring PC.
2. Take notes or Record screen of the PC using freewares.

It would be bit of a difficult process as your company is not willing to pay for user session recording services.

Also, https://www.inspectlet.com/plans have a free plan but with limited quantity and features though.

Answer (score 0):

Morae claim to be able to test mobile devices, from the [video on their home page](https://www.techsmith.com/smartplayer?mp4=https://assets.techsmith.com/Video/mkt-product-morae/morae-mobiledevicetest.mp4&webm=https://assets.techsmith.com/Video/mkt-product-morae/morae-mobiledevicetest.webm&&&&theme=morae&title=morae-mobiledevicetest.mp4&embedIFrameId=tsc_player16873&autoplay=false&disablefullframe=false).

They basically followed option 3 by looking at the video.